# Configure which network interface Tor listens on

Tags: configuration

Linux/networking noob here- I've been curious as to how I can make an onion server listen on a different interface than the default for all connections, including SSH. I know that Tor works on localhost, so I'm not trying to change that, but I am trying to add a little more anonymity to the stack by essentially faking the server's IP address through use of a virtual network interface. If I'm crazy and this absolutely will not work, is there another similar solution that would make Tor and the webserver see a false IP address?